# What was the reason for Doug Stamper's final decision about Rachel?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

Why did Doug Stamper finally decide to kill Rachel in season 3 of *House of Cards*?

Answer (score 0):

I think in short Doug was going to let her go. I think she talked too much... she gave him the reason. He put 2 + 2 together and thought well she tried to kill me after I really helped her and then murdered a innocent person so she was not a good person at all. The way she tells it. I think he killed her exactly the same way she killed Cassie. She had the fake ID. She told the story about the Cassie Lockhart as if she were a real person. Like she had spent time with her. She was in the area the body of the dead girl mistaken for her. I think she murdered Cassie Lockhart for her ID and had a pro put her image with clean ID and documents. Meaning she befriended this girl and really did even more horrible thing. If she was capable of this... well Doug figured it out...